# Big Subview to Fit in Another Small Subview

Tags: ios, uiview, uilabel, subview

Im trying to create a secondary view to my main view. This subview needs to be of small height and it needs to fit another big UIView with a label in it.

Problem is that when I'm using UIView addSubview, the third UIView will be shown out of bounds of secondary UIView.

For ease of understanding my situation, I have created those Subviews using Interface builder with the photo and the result on simulator with the photo.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

1. Interface Builder 
   http://postimage.org/image/ofi3m05v3/
2. Simulator
   http://postimage.org/image/x2qps3w2f/

Comment: Solution is to use UIView.clipsToBounds = YES;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to activate the clip to bounds property of some of those views.

```
fooView.clipsToBounds=YES;
```

That should solve your problem.  Just set the appropriate views to clip to their bounds.